# How to taking time zone into account when using Date#to_time method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have a Rails project that has `Tokyo(+0900)` time zone.

And OS local time zone is `Bangkok(+0700)`.

`Date#to_time` method doesn't take time zone into account.

```
Date.current.to_time
2016-06-21 00:00:00 +0700
```

I'm using now `Time.zone.parse` method:

```
Time.zone.parse(Date.current.to_s)
Tue, 21 Jun 2016 00:00:00 JST +09:00
```

Is there a better way to convert a date to time with the proper time zone?

### Time.zone

```
Time.zone
#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fa8402f86f0 @name="Tokyo", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Asia/Tokyo>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: -578044800>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: 32400,0,JST>>,nil>>
```

#### config/application.rb

```
module MyProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
   config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you know about [TZInfo](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo)? It's considered robust (follows DST), you would say `TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Bangkok').now`

Comment: The method could be convenient, but my question is how to convert `Date` instance to `Time` instance considering time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in Ruby 2.4

https://wyeworks.com/blog/2016/6/22/behavior-changes-in-ruby-2.4

Answer (score 1):

[to_time](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Conversions/to_time) by default takes local time zone to convert the time in time zone, and it accepts only :local or :utc time zone in the parameter. so you have to set the time zone before you apply `.to_time` on `Date` object.

```
Time.zone = "Tokyo"
irb(main):046:0> Date.current.to_time
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2016 09:00:00 JST +09:00
```

OR you can user `.use_zone` with the block to keep that set that time zone for the particular block.

```
irb(main):046:0> Time.use_zone("Tokyo"){Date.current.to_time}
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2016 09:00:00 JST +09:00
```

Above result will always give you time with respect to `UTC` so time will be added with respect to selected time zone. if you want it to be set to start of the day you can use [beginning_of_day](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/beginning_of_day)

```
Time.zone = "Tokyo"
irb(main):048:0> Date.current.to_time.beginning_of_day
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2016 00:00:00 JST +09:00

irb(main):049:0> Time.use_zone("Tokyo"){ Date.current.to_time.beginning_of_day }
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2016 00:00:00 JST +09:00
```

Using `Date` object for `Time Zone` operations is not a better approach, always use `Time` object to deal with `Time Zone`

Time.zone = "Tokyo"

```
irb(main):050:0> Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2016 00:00:00 ICT +09:00

irb(main):051:0> Time.use_zone("Tokyo"){ Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day }
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2016 00:00:00 JST +09:00
```

[Do’s and Don’ts of Rails Timezones](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)

Comment: Yeah, I set time zone but, `#to_time` method doesn't reflect it.
`Time.zone = 'Tokyo'; Date.current.to_time #=> 2016-06-22 00:00:00 +0700`.

Comment: Can you please verify that the timezone is set properly by checking `Time.zone` after assigning it.

Comment: can you please paste the code where you have set the timezone?

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. I added info about `Time.zone` and how to set the time zone.